# Is there a way to procedurally loop processes in shader nodes

Tags: node-editor, mathematics, procedural

I'm trying to make a node group that can convert values into "binary" (i know the value will still technically be base 10). I made a set of nodes that if they are recursively placed over and over it can convert the number successfully, but you would have to do that manually and the amount of times you would need to repeat the function would vary based on the size of the number you are trying to convert. This is mainly a challenge to do this myself so if there is a better way to convert decimal to binary (other than a single node i may be overlooking) i don't need to know, i just want to loop sections of node code. Even if my plan doesn't work it would still be good to know a way to procedurally repeat sections of a node network, maybe controlled by a value which describes the amount of times the function is repeated.

Comment: Feel free to berate my question, if i didnt not phrase it well enough or i was too vague for you to answer, lemme know.

Comment: Hello, may I ask what is your end goal in this challenge ?